how to cat proof my patio without railings
I’m about to move to a new 1 bedroom apartment that I’m renting so no drills or anything that will alter the structure of the building. Current apartment, my patio has railings so I wrapped metal wires around it and secured it with cable ties. But this new apartment doesn’t have rails; it’s raised bricks.
How should I go about covering the open area with wires or nettings? What will hold it in place without drilling holes into the wall.



This question is rather broad. We're not a discussion forum. You need to come up with a direction and ask something more specific about your approach. See [ask] and take the [tour].

If you do not mind seeing your own blood flowing, maybe a cat harness.  Limit how far the cat can travel instead of trying to keep it inside an area.

Dumb question: Are you keeping cats out or in?

@spuck not a dumb question at all!

Depending on the width (or the height), one might use expandable curtain rods. We have a couple in our shower area serving as towel holders. One tube telescopes inside the other with a threaded fitting within. Turning one tube to the other causes the internal threaded fitting to expand, locking it in place.
@keshlam's suggestion of a frame is also a good one and is not as limited by "stock" sizes. I'd find it practical to create channel shapes for left and right, top and bottom with cross beams to hold the netting/mesh/wire blocking.

This image represents one-quarter of the overall construction. Depending on the strength and dimensions, the yellow legs may not be necessary. Duplicate this and rotate in each corner, then suspend netting from the cross pieces, tacked to the side bars. It's likely one would need to create an arch-shaped solid blocking for the curve at the top. Cats will find (or make) any exit needed.
Note that individual components are not to scale. I see that there's limited overlap room in the opening, so the yellow members are quite excessively sized in this representation.

Simplest fix I see would be to build a wooden  frame that fits tightly inside the periphery of the wall, rather than the opening in the wall, and put mosquito screen over that. No modification to building, no question of whether the cat can push it out of the way. It might need intermediate cross pieces to support the junction between strips of netting, unless you are willing to take the time to weave those together, but that's still something that can be done with not much more than a staple gun.

Easiest would be to use shower curtain spring-tension rods, such as these at Walmart and at Amazon, to hold some netting. They're available from ~US$3 and up. Netting could be held in place with shower curtain hooks such as these from Walmart, making the net easy to open.
The rods are not very strong, so you might need a few to hold the netting, and they might pop loose in strong winds. Also, use a loose-weave netting to offer less resistance to wind (or use a tighter weave, and add more rods to make the opening bug-, as well as cat-proof).
All links are for the purpose of illustration only.
